# Change part of the CSS class using ngClass

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have multiple classes apply to an element. Is it possible to change only 1 class, not the all of the classes?

For example,

```
<span ng-class="{'result warning' : error, 'result passing' : !error}"></span>
```

As you can see, I have to duplicate *result* class in both of the conditions. Is there a way to not have to repeat it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="result" ng-class="{'warning': error, 'passing': !error}"></span>
```

ng-class can add/remove classes - it doesn't over-write existing classes unless they are specified in ng-class.